# Analysis: Proof checking and help on 2nd part (Integrals)

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, proof-verification

So I have the question,

$f(x)= x$  if $0$ $\leq$ $x$ $\leq$ $1$ and

$f(x)= x+2$ if $1<x$ $\leq$ $2$ (the same f(x) I just couldn't figure out how to do the big bracket)

Part 1 is asking me to find that if $\int_{[0,2]}$ exists and it's value.

For this part I was able to do a summation of both x and x+2.

For x I was able to turn the summation into $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1/n)^2$$((1+n)/2)*n$

Which I was able to solve to find that the answer for that is 1/2.

Now for x+2 I did the same thing and turned the summation into a limit that is $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $1/n$$(1/n+2+n/n+2)n/2$ which I was able to solve for 5/2.

And to solve for the value I add 1/2 and 5/2 and get 3.

I am assuming this solves it and shows the existence. Do I do anything else?

$\\$

Note: These are both part of the same problem so the f(t) that's being referred to is referring to f(x) in part 1.

Now part 2 is what I am really stuck on. It gives me $F(x) =\int_{[0,x]}$
 $f(t)dt$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 2$. For this one I am supposed to show that it's continuous but not differentiable at $p=1$. I drew a picture of the two lines and I see how it is but honestly I don't really know how to start.

I had originally tried showing it continuous first but I had taken it by parts of x and x+2 but that turned out that I was doing it for f(x) and not F(x). Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $F(x)$ in two separate cases: first, when $x \leq 1$; second, when $x > 1$. For the second case, you may want to use the fact that 
$$\int_0^x f(t) \, dt = \int_0^1 f(t) \, dt + \int_1^x f(t) \, dt,$$
if that's something that you know.